# Отправить SOAP WSDL через PHP и получить ответ

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

Добрый день. Подскажите. Сервер по адресу: http://example1.com/CRM/Service1.svc
мне нужно отправить SOAP запрос:

```
<x:Envelope xmlns:x="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:bus="http://www.examle2.com/BusinessServer">
<x:Header/>
<x:Body>
    <bus:GetCustomerInformation>
        <bus:CardNumber>0420200015688</bus:CardNumber>
    </bus:GetCustomerInformation>
</x:Body>
```

По средствам php используя готовый WSDL расположенный по адресу example3.com/wsdl.xml
и получить ответ.
Ответ в формате:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Body>
    <GetCustomerInformationResponse xmlns="http://www.example2.com/BusinessServer">
        <GetCustomerInformationResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ExternalCustomerSoapServer" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <a:CardNumber>0420200015688</a:CardNumber>
            <a:City>Praha-8</a:City>
            <a:CityExtra i:nil="true"/>
            <a:Email>pupkinbest@bestmail.ciom</a:Email>
            <a:EmployeeNumber i:nil="true"/>
            <a:Fax i:nil="true"/>
            <a:Gender>F</a:Gender>
            <a:IsBlocked>false</a:IsBlocked>
            <a:IsInactive>false</a:IsInactive>
            <a:LanguageCode i:nil="true"/>
            <a:Name i:nil="true"/>
            <a:NationCode i:nil="true"/>
            <a:Phone>12345678</a:Phone>
            <a:PoBox i:nil="true"/>
            <a:Street>PUSHKINA</a:Street>
            <a:StreetExtra i:nil="true"/>
            <a:StreetNumber>/785</a:StreetNumber>
            <a:StreetNumberExtra i:nil="true"/>
            <a:SurName>PUPKIN</a:SurName>
            <a:ZipCode>1234</a:ZipCode>
        </GetCustomerInformationResult>
    </GetCustomerInformationResponse>
</s:Body>
```

Есть ли какие примеры как это может работать в моем случае?
Руками если отправлять запрос все работает, но нужно сделать средствами php

Comment: Если вас устраивает ответ, то отметьте его как правильный, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать [родной php клиент soap](http://php.net/manual/ru/soapclient.soapclient.php):

```
$client=new SoapClient('http://example3.com/wsdl.xml', array('trace' => true,'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE));
print_r($client->GetCustomerInformation('0420200015688'));
print_r($client->__getLastRequestHeaders());
prin_r($client->__getLastRequest());
```